# Undefined reference to PCL in .so

Tags: linker, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to compile this tutorial from PCL
http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber
My class is GrabKinect.h and GrabKinect.cpp

I put my main in another file main.cpp and I got 7 errors like this error:
/lib/libGrabKinect.so: undefined reference to 'pcl...'

I'm compiling with Qt

Comment: ...and I bet you expect the linker to know things it cannot possibly know...

Comment: And what should I do? in my CMakeLists.txt I told main to use PCL, is it not enough?

Comment: It should - what exactly is the invocation of the linker?

Comment: I think the problem is with CMake, doing generate I obtained WARNING: Target "main" request link to directory "home/PCL/common/include". Targets may link only to libraries. CMake is dropping the item. I installed PCL with apt-get; where can I find the library?